# Named service won't start CentOS 7

Tags: centos7

After an update of CustomBuild via DirectAdmin the named service doesn't start anymore from my CentOS 7 server. I have tried to start named service via SSH, but I don't know how to solve this issue. I think I have to recreate vps.myname.nl.db, but how?

```
[root@vps ~]# /usr/bin/systemctl start named.service 2>&1
Job for named.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                                                                         See "systemctl status named.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@vps ~]# journalctl -xe
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/I
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loade
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone davps.axc.nl/IN: loaded
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone othername.nl/IN: loaded s
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone othernamedirect.nl/IN: lo
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone vps.myname.nl/I
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone vps.myname.nl/I
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: _default/vps.myname.
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone anothername.eu/IN: lo
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone anotherothername.eu/IN: lo
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone andanothername.nl/IN: loaded
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl systemd[1]: named.service: control proces
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Inte
-- Subject: Unit named.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit named.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered fa
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl systemd[1]: named.service failed.
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl polkitd[515]: Unregistered Authentication
lines 2506-2528/2528 (END)
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone davps.axc.nl/IN: loaded serial 2018020200
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone othername.nl/IN: loaded serial 2018020500
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone othernamedirect.nl/IN: loaded serial 2018020500
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone vps.myname.nl/IN: loading from master file /var/named/vps.myname.nl.db failed: file not found
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone vps.myname.nl/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: _default/vps.myname.nl/IN: file not found
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone anothername.eu/IN: loaded serial 2018111201
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone anotherothername.eu/IN: loaded serial 2018111201
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl bash[1321]: zone andanothername.nl/IN: loaded serial 2018111200
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 02 12:57:44 vps.myname.nl systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
-- Subject: Unit named.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit named.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The system is not starting because of this missing file `/var/named/vps.myname.nl.db`.

You have several options:

- remove this zone definition from the configuration if you don't need it

  - start searching in `/etc/named.conf` or some included conf file
- create empty zone file to be able to start it up

  - the most quick option is to run `cp /var/named/named.empty /var/named/vps.myname.nl.db` (please not that the zone will be empty)
- create empty zone (see previous bullet) and then to the new file add the records you need

then the named daemon would be able to start

Comment: Thanks Kamil! Adding the empty zone file did the trick. vps.myname.nl is of course the hostname of the server. Is it necessary to add NS, A records and such? It is still empty, but everything is working correctly I think.